# Speeding Up Conversion of Complex type to Another Complex type for Serialization in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working with **.Net Core 2.1** and **Visual Studio 2017**.

**PROBLEM**
 I am working with a 3rd party `dll` `class` object which does not implement `ISerializable`. I am trying to convert 4k+ objects of this type to another custom type and then serialize these to pass back from an API to a web application. It takes about 55 seconds to convert 1000 objects to the serializable kind for a grand total of 2:30 minutes of wait time for the API to return the `JSON`.

**What I've Tried**
 I have tried starting multiple tasks to convert a batch of 1000 3rd party objects to custom serializable class objects then merging all task results into one List for serialization. I have tried switching from using a List to using an Array. I have tried using `Parallel.ForEach` and `ConcurrentBag` to do conversion. No matter which way I try it seems to take around 50 - 60 seconds to get 1000 of these objects converted to the custom serializable type. I suspect most of this is coming from the call to `new` on each iteration of the 3rd party list. I also tried just string concatenation with a String Builder to create the JSON data result by iterating the 3rd party list and placing the properties into the string via concatenation, this also seemed really slow do to calls to `.ToString()`

If anyone can give me some help on this, I would really like to improve the performance time. I read that using `struct` may be a better solution, but I have not yet tried that. I was hoping there may be a way to do this quickly and still use `classes`.

**CODE EXAMPLE**

```
//OnBaseSearchDocument is my custom class which is serializable
OnBaseSearchDocument[] items = new OnBaseSearchDocument[sizeOfList];

//The class itself
public class OnBaseSearchDocument
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long DocumentId { get; set; }

    public string DocumentType { get; set; }

    public string DocStorageDate { get; set; }

    public string DocRevisionDate { get; set; }

    public string DocumentDate { get; set; }

    //Switched to using long for dates so I didn't call .ToString() on DateTimes of 3rd party class
    //For the string props above
    public long DocDate { get; set; }

    public long DocReviseDate { get; set; }

    public long DocStoreDate { get; set; }
```

}

```
//Trying to convert
//items is an array of custom class type I created that are serializable
//Hyland.Unity.Document is a 3rd party class contained in a dll - Not Serializable
foreach(Hyland.Unity.Document d in dl)
{
    items[counter] = new OnBaseSearchDocument() { DocumentId = d.ID, Name = d.Name, DocumentType = d.DocumentType.Name, DocDate = d.DocumentDate.Ticks, DocReviseDate = d.LatestRevision.Date.Ticks, DocStoreDate = d.DateStored.Ticks };
    counter++;
 }
```

**EDIT**

So, I switched to using a `struct` instead of a `class`:

```
[Serializable]
public struct StructOnBaseSearchDocument
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long DocumentId { get; set; }

    public string DocumentType { get; set; }

    public string DocStorageDate { get; set; }

    public string DocRevisionDate { get; set; }

    public string DocumentDate { get; set; }
}

for (int i = 0; i < dl.Count; i++)
{
    Structs.StructOnBaseSearchDocument st = new Structs.StructOnBaseSearchDocument()
    {
        DocumentId = dl[i].ID,
        Name = dl[i].Name,
        DocumentType = dl[i].DocumentType.Name,
        DocStorageDate = dl[i].DateStored.ToString(),
        DocRevisionDate = dl[i].LatestRevision.Date.ToString(),
        DocumentDate = dl[i].DocumentDate.ToString()
    };

    foundDocs[counter] = st;
    counter++;
}
```

I used a stopwatch to time for conversion - 1000 objects of type `Hyland.Unity.Document` converted to Custom `struct` in above loop took 1 minute.
Switching to `struct` has not improved performance at all.

**UPDATE**
So, I removed the setting of Date's to string and the calls to `.ToString()` on `DateTimes` and the performance was 1000 times better, the loop executed in less than 1 second compared to 1 minute with the calls to `.ToString()` on `DateTime`. So, I guess I found the bottleneck, but I could use some help on this as I still need to pass these dates back to the web app.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
 //Removed the setting of the string representations of DateTime's in the `struct`
 //no calls to `DateTime.ToString()`
 for (int i = 0; i < dl.Count; i++)
    {
        Structs.StructOnBaseSearchDocument st = new Structs.StructOnBaseSearchDocument()
        {
            DocumentId = dl[i].ID,
            Name = dl[i].Name,
            DocumentType = dl[i].DocumentType.Name
            //DocStorageDate = dl[i].DateStored.ToString(),
            //DocRevisionDate = dl[i].LatestRevision.Date.ToString(),
            //DocumentDate = dl[i].DocumentDate.ToString()
        };

        foundDocs[counter] = st;
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about the DLLs (maybe post an example) as well as the serialization logic?

Comment: @Slothario Added example code and explanations in comments.

Comment: Is it possible to use something like protobuf or are you stuck with JSON?

Comment: It's my own creation so I could possibly add more to the project, what is the benefit of `protobuf` and how much overhead will it add to my project and does it cost anything?

Comment: I believe the protobuf serialization and deserialization can be much faster, but you'll need to confirm that yourself. From my understanding it's faster and lighter weight than JSON, with the downside that communication is no longer human-readable. You don't have to convert and reconvert all your data to strings anymore and it doesn't pass field names back and forth.

Comment: It's not the `serialization` that is slow, its the conversion from 3rd party class objects to custom class objects.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your post closely enough. I think you should definitely try using structs next, I'm afraid. I've read that they can be way faster, and it seems that might be your main bottleneck.

Comment: @Slothario That's what I'm thinking at this point, I was just hoping there may be a way using classes which I didn't know about or find in research.

Comment: If you get good results, post again here and let me know how it goes!

Comment: Have you tried serializing the objects directly to JSON? Also have you tried NOT using tasks or paralellism? That may be slowing you down... Try using just a normal foreach and map all the objects to a List<> of your class... Then serializing that to JSON

Comment: Your objects do not look that complex..... Mapping a few thousand and serializing to JSON should be pretty quick...   So I am guessing your problem has to be somewhere else...  Also it could be that some of those properties in the 3rd Party object are getting the information for an IO operation like database access, COM API, Web API or some other form of external source...

Comment: Please give us information on what this 3rd party objects are and where they come from... Also please show us the code where you serialize this to JSON

Answer (score 0):

(Since I can't post a comment, I have to post suggestions as an answer)

The first thing I think you need to determine is where exactly your bottleneck is.  At a guess, it is in the interaction with `dl`.  Perhaps it takes a long time to be created or it may be lazily evaluated (that is, each time through the loop, there could be some really expensive call which is where the time is being spent).  A couple of ways you can pinpoint where the slowness is coming from:
 1. Wrap some of the statements in a `Stopwatch`.  For example, you may want to time how long it takes to materialize each item.

```
var sw = Stopwatch();
foreach(Hyland.Unity.Document d in dl)
{
    // note: the stop is here intentionally to see how long 
    // it takes to materialize each item
    sw.Stop();
    // if this is taking a long time, the bottleneck is (likely) 
    // in whatever the 3rd party .dll is doing
    items[counter] = new OnBaseSearchDocument() { DocumentId = d.ID, Name = d.Name, DocumentType = d.DocumentType.Name, DocDate = d.DocumentDate.Ticks, DocReviseDate = d.LatestRevision.Date.Ticks, DocStoreDate = d.DateStored.Ticks };
    counter++;
    sw.Start();
 }
```

you could also wrap the instantiation of `OnBaseSearchDocument` but I would be shocked if this was the problem (assuming property access is fast on the `Hyland.Unity.Document` object)
 2. Use a profiler (this should probably be #1)

Answer (score 0):

So after some investigating, i found that the issue was a call to this property to get a Revision `datetime` value. This is extremely weird as it's a property not a method so I don't really understand what causes all the overhead.:

```
dl[i].LatestRevision.Date.Ticks, //This is the problem child - apparently calling .LatestRevision
                                 //causes massive overhead, the other two
                                 //DateTimes are no problem at all, loop executes in
                                 //under 1/10th of a second.
```

**SOLUTION**
   I no longer bother returning the latest revision date and make this a singular call if the user wants to view the revision date, they click a button which calls the API and returns a singular value for that particular item. Case closed. Thanks everybody for your input.

Answer (score -2):

If you're hosting this in the cloud, Azure functions could be ideal. Store your DLLs in blob storage, put your DLL conversion tasks in to a queue, and then have Azure functions consume from the queue.

You could easily have your code run on hundreds of machines at once, and you'd stop paying for them as soon as the task was finished.

Comment: and if he isn't?

Comment: @Slothario I am not hosting this in the Cloud.